# How to hide the applications in iExplorer

Tags: iphone

I'm developing one application. When I install my app in iphone and if I connect iphone to PC then all my application data will be accessing from iExplorer. Is there any chance to hide my application in iExplorer?

Comment: no, there is no way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application data will always be visible to the user with the right tools. You should not waste any effort trying to obfuscate or hide it.

If you wish to explicitly enable encryption on certain files, you can look into the data protection APIs offered in the iOS SDK. This will protect user files in the case that their phone or device is stolen. The user must have a passcode set for this to work however.

Comment: Basically my app contain some folders,that total folders data is the total application.If user get that flders data then what is the use of my app

Comment: That's a good question. What *is* the use of your app? If you are trying to sell data without the user being able to copy that data,  you're getting into the realm of DRM.